# Is there any way to limit changes to a directory files to a designated user?

Tags: azure-devops

I am familiar with the concept of branch policy and branch permissions in Azure Devops.

Do we have a similar feature for directories in a repository so that I can limit changes to a directory files to a designated user? For example, only user-a can change the files in a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to limit changes to a directory files to a designated user?

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

Currently, permissions can only be set for all repos and individual repos. But it is not yet possible to set permissions on a specific repo.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]